# Why is my VBO updated on 2nd click?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, 3d, vbo

I have this method (InvertPolygonMesh) which basically takes an array (my VBO) and inverts all vertices along the Z axis. This method is directly invoked by the click of a button (IBAction). Now for some odd reason the VBO doesn't change on the first click, but it does get inverted on every subsequent click after the 1st one.

Why is there no update for the 1st click?

Method is below:

```
-(void)InvertPolygonMesh
{
    NSLog(@"Invert mesh data.");
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBufferPhoto);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_meshVertexData), g_meshVertexData, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    int index = 0;
    bool edgeCase = false;

    for (int row = 0; row < MAP_SIZE; row += STEP_SIZE)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < MAP_SIZE; col += STEP_SIZE)
        {
            g_meshVertexData[index].vertex.z = 255 - g_meshVertexData[index].vertex.z;
            ++index;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Resolved. See answer below.

Comment: Why did you post a question and then delete it immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i fixed this by calling glBindBuffer and glBufferData functions AFTER the mesh vertices have been updated. Resolved !!!